# Shell function error "invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: shell, vb6

After editing the batch file I want to run it. When I run it from the desktop, it runs properly, but from my program, I get the error:

> invalid procedure call or argument

The batch file is in use until the VB6 program ends.

```
dRetVal = Shell("C:\Users\Theo\Desktop\BatchName.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus)
```

What is wrong with this line? Or do you have other suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Batch files are run by `C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE`. CMD requires switches `/c` to run and exit and `/k` to keep running after the batch finishes. See `cmd /?`.

Comment: @Morales Batovski Thank you very much.

Comment: @Noodles I think I must thank Mr. Noodles.
Now the statement is as follows:

dRetVal = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""G:\Documents\CheckPoint\BatchName.bat""", vbMinimizedNoFocus)

How do I indicate problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files are run by `C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE`. `CMD` requires switches `/c` to run and exit and `/k` to keep running after the batch finishes. See `cmd /?`